# reload cogs on discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I try to make a discord bot with cogs that i woudn't need to restart the bot every time I'm changing the code.
I have done this:

```
from Bot import bot
from checks import check_if_me
from cogs.tracking import Tracking
from discord.ext import commands

token = ''

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    bot.add_cog(Tracking(bot))
    print(f'ready {bot.latency}')


@bot.command(name='reload')
@commands.check(check_if_me)
async def reload_cog(ctx):
    bot.remove_cog('Tracking')
    bot.add_cog(Tracking(bot))




bot.run(token)
```

but it's just load the same cog and not the new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do that, you would need to actually reload the extension rather than the class cog. An extension refers to the whole file.

Discord.py allows you to load an extension using `bot.load_extension` to avoid users from importing the cog manually.

You can do this by defined a setup() function in your cog file, this will receive `Bot` instance for you to add your cog. After that, you can use `bot.load_extension` in the main file and use `bot.reload_extension` to achieve your current problem.

Example:

**cogs\tracking.py**

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Tracking(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot # This is so you can access Bot instance in your cog

# You must have this function for `bot.load_extension` to call
def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Tracking(bot))
```

**\main.py**

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(...)
# "cogs.tracking" refers to "cogs\tracking.py" file
bot.load_extension("cogs.tracking")

# A command to call the reload
@bot.command()
async def reload(ctx):
    # Reloads the file, thus updating the Cog class.
    bot.reload_extension("cogs.tracking")
```

Comment: tnx but whyits happend?

Comment: Because you're only removing and re-adding the same class object. Fundamentally, class are loaded once when you "import" a file as an object. In this case, bot.load_extension imports the entire file, reload_extension reloads the import will a new class object rather than the same one.